# Where are the actions in my controller- Rails4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, action

I dont know where are the actions in my controller file. This is the content:

```
class MarcasController < InheritedResources::Base

  private

def marca_params
  params.require(:marca).permit(:nombre, :comentarios)
end
end
```

Whats going on??

Comment: How can I edit them???. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The actions are implicitly added by the inherited_resources gem. Presumably this is someone else's code that you're working on?

Answer (score 0):

`MarcasController` is your controller,
`marca_params` is your action. However it's private, so it can't be accessed by router.

If you want your action to be accessible from a website, you will need to do the following:

**create a public action**

```
class MarcasController < InheritedResources::Base

def index
end


  private

def marca_params
  params.require(:marca).permit(:nombre, :comentarios)
end
end
```

**In your `routes.rb` **

```
get '/marcas' => 'marcas#index'
```

**Create corresponding view, add file `app/views/marcas/index.html.erb`.**

Then you will be able to access your action.

usually if you need a controller that needs CRUD actions (create, read, update delete). you can run a rails command to create all the files you need.

```
rails generate scaffold marcas nombre:text comentarios:text
```

Answer (score 0):

controller actions are another way to say "a method that responds to an http request". They are defined in your routes file like:

```
post   'marcas/',           :to => 'marcas#create'
```

They are usually spoken of that way in the view or in terms of a request. So

```
class MarcasController < InheritedResources::Base

  # create action
  def create
    @marca = @marcas.create(marcas_params)
  end

  private # good for strong params and other private methods
  def marca_params
    params.require(:marca).permit(:nombre, :comentarios)
  end

end
```